# String name in strings.xml caused error in R.java that cannot be edited manually in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generated

I have been working on an app for some time in eclipse. I am using ADT, Build: v22.0.1-685705. The other day, I accidentally named a string with a space in the name. I eventually fixed the name, but in the R.java file, it still has a space in it. Because of the space, it says that there is a syntax error and I need to delete the second word. Unfortunately, because it is a generated file, whenever I delete it, it reverts to the generated version. I have run the clean command but the variable is still there. Here is where the variable is located in the R.java:

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int Last Update=0x7f090001;
}
```

This is the string that caused it:

```
<string name="Last Update">Last Updated: July 8, 2013</string>
```

Even after removing the space in strings.xml, it still generates it in R.java with a space. 
I have done a lot of work on this app and I really don't want to have to restart.
What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't think that your question is detailed enough to get an answer.  You may have to provide more context and code.

Comment: I added more info. What I have said is all that I know about this.

Comment: You said you cleaned it many times. Did you try to rebuild it by doing `Build > Rebuild Project` ?

Comment: Yes. After doing some digging I found that it wasn't the string that caused the problem, but a button who's name had a space in it. So when I took out the space and ran Project>Clean again, it fixed it.

Comment: Cool. You worked out.